# Android custom arrayadapter constructor issue

Tags: java, android, constructor, android-arrayadapter

I am making a custom arrayAdapter for my listview, but a simple thing like my super constructor is messing me up!

```
private ArrayAdapter<ScheduleTime> timeHold;
    //make proper constructor, see use ticket types
    public TimeTableAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayAdapter<ScheduleTime> timesTable) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, timesTable);
        this.timeHold = timesTable;
    }
```

I get the error on the `super` line:

`super(context, textViewResourceId, timesTable);`

`The constructor SimpleAdapter(Context, int, ArrayAdapter<ScheduleTime>) is undefined`

What am I missing here? my above constructor clearly has all of those elements

Comment: When it says, `The constructor SimpleAdapter(Context, int, ArrayAdapter<ScheduleTime>) is undefined`, it means that those are the **wrong** elements. It *is telling* you that you have those elements, but that is not defined for a Simple Adapter. As @JB Nizet said, a Simple Adapter has different `super` arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because the constructor you are defining takes a certain parameter list, it doesn't mean the super class has that constructor. After all, you can define any arbitary parameter list for your constructor.

The super constructor you are trying to call is closest to ones in the ArrayAdapter class, but the error message suggests you are trying to inherit from SimpleAdapter. Have you got this right? If it should be ArrayAdapter, the last argument needs to be the array (or List) of the objects which back the adapter, instead of just a single object of that type.

If it is SimpleAdapter, the only constructor is
[here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html#SimpleAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20java.util.List%3C?%20extends%20java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20?%3E%3E,%20int,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D%29), which looks quite a bit different.

Answer (score 1):

`super` is used to call the constructor of the superclass, the class you're extending. Look at [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html): the constructor of `SimpleAdapter` has different arguments.