# ListAdapter error when call another fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

```
  private class ContactListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<import_fragment.Contact> {
    public ContactListAdapter() {
        super (main_fragment.this, R.layout.fragment_import, Contacts);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (view == null)
            view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_import, parent, false);

        import_fragment.Contact currentContact = Contacts.get(position);

        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
        name.setText(currentContact.getName());
        TextView phone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.phoneNumber);
        phone.setText(currentContact.getPhone());
        TextView email = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.emailAddress);
        email.setText(currentContact.getEmail());
        TextView address = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cAddress);
        address.setText(currentContact.getAddress());


        return view;
    }
```

When i try to change R.layout.import_fragment (My other fragment) this line  `super (main_fragment.this, R.layout.fragment_import, Contacts);`
 
has an error say *Cannot resolve method 'super(com.al3almya.users.al3almya.main_fragment, int, java.util.List);

i get this error when i type my other fragment layout.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android custom arrayadapter constructor issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099901/android-custom-arrayadapter-constructor-issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First parameter of `ArrayAdapter` is `Context` but you are passing `com.al3almya.users.al3almya.main_fragment`, which is wrong.

Change your method signature to this

```
public ContactListAdapter(Context cntx) {
    super (cntx, R.layout.fragment_import, Contacts);
}
```

and when you call the adapter use this

```
new ContactListAdapter(this); // if called from activity
```

or

```
new ContactListAdapter(getActivity); // if called from fragment
```